# What is my directory when writing files in Android?

Tags: java, android

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

When trying to delete one of those files, this is what I use, but it's returning false.

```
String tag = v.getTag().toString();
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+tag);
String s = new Boolean (file.exists()).toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 1500).show();
file.delete();
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Use `getFileStreamPath(FILENAME)` to find your file. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with [`openFileOutput(String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is stored.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Your current working directory.</s>

To help diagnose the problem, use `file.getAbsolutePath()` to see the full path.

<s>It could also be a permissions problem, if you're trying to delete from another application.  If so, you may need to change to MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE (insecure), or restructure your code so the create and delete are called by the same app.</s>

EDIT: That was mostly incorrect.  I didn't realize that openFileOutput didn't use the current working directory.

Comment: What is the default working directory for an Android application?

Comment: Oh what, how do i set working directories, or where do i find my current working directory?

Comment: /data/data/$package_name/files

Comment: @pst, I don't know, but you can get it from `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.  @Marc, you can't change it in Java code (I was wrong before).

Comment: The concept of `user.dir` is not as useful as one might imagine. It is _not_ the way to create files in Android. See Dianne Hackborn's response in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/qP90fz7hPqo). (For instance, [this post](http://java-tech-other.blogspot.com/2011/02/is-android-dalvik-java.html) shows that at least on some systems, `user.dir` is `/` (where apps certainly don't have permission to create files).

Answer (score 1):

Use same contents as 'FILENAME' variable in your first snippet in the second snippet while trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Video";
        File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
        RootFile.mkdir();

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(RootFile, "Sample.mp4"));
```

i used this code to save the video files to non-default location. Hope this will be useful to you.By default it is storing in sd card

For each application the Android system creates a "data/data/package of  the application" directory. 
Files are saved in the "files" folder under this directory

to change the default directory the above code will be used

the default working directory can be displayed using fileobject.getAbsolutePath()